# possible contradiction to Cayley's formula (how many possible labeled trees with n vertices)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am supposed to solve the following question, but my answer does not follow Cayley's formula.

**Question:** how many possible trees are there with $4$ vertices

My answer is $17$, but Cayley's formula states there would only be $16$.

[here is an image with my work for this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqdUy.jpg)

the question does not specify where the tree is labeled or unlabeled

can someone tell me where I messed up on this problem?

Comment: The trees should be labelled. Now note that your first two pictures are really the same: one vertex as a hub. And your third picture isn't labeled. So go back to the drawing board (literally).

Comment: Cayley's formula gives the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 different star graphs, one centered at each vertex. Then, to count the path graphs, there are 4!/2, there are 4! to order the vertices, and two ways to list each path graph, such as 1234 $\equiv$ 4321.

And 4+4!/2=16.